# synchronous http get request in Angular 5 service?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-services

I have a very big project with a lot of components and services.

I want to build another service which all of the components use. This service will be calling http get request which retrieves the order of components(like a config) and according to this the components will be ordered on the page. I want to make the call synchronous so that the components don't load until the order is retrieved. I want to do this because I don't want to flicker the display after the components are loaded. basically like a synchronous ajax call.

My code is as below

Service

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()

export class ConfigService {
    constructor() {

    }
    getUserConfigFromDB() {
        //http request
        ;

    }
}
```

Component

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {ConfigService} from "../app/services/ConfigService"

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.configService.getUserConfigFromDB()
  }
}
```

This service will be used by a lot of components.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT1: I think I was not clear. I cannot change anything in the components except call the getUserConfigFromDB() method. I'm looking for an exact alternative to ajax(async:false). I want the page to freeze until i get response from the api.

Comment: What is the structure of the config? How exactly will the components depend on the config?

Comment: its an object with the key being the component name and value being the order(number)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a sync http request, just put the http request in a resolver. The page won't load until the resolver has fetched the data and thus you won't get the flicker you are talking about.

Comment: This is the correct solution. https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data

Comment: No, he is asking about avoiding flicker on page load and resolvers are the answer

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should create a `ContainerComponent`. This `ContainerComponent` will call the method that you're talking about and will set the config as a property on the `ContainerComponent` class.

You can then place all your components in a `div` in the template of this `ContainerComponent` with an `*ngIf` on it. This will render only if the `config` is set after calling your service method.

I'm not really sure how you're planning on using this `config` to order the components though.